# Component Navigation , pop from backstack with arguments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

Let's say I have three fragments, A, B, C;

A -> B  <-> C

Between B and C it is a circular relationship. Either B or C fragments requires `arguments`, example

```
     val args = Bundle()

     args.putString("StringKeyBC", argValueBtoC)       
     findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fragmentB_to_fragmentC, args, null)

     args.putString("StringKeyCB", argValueCtoB)       
     findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fragmentC_to_fragmentB, args, null)
```

The problem is that every time I move between B & C, the fragments are added to back stack and I don't want that. If the fragment is already to back stack I want just to pop it, but if I use `popBackStack` I can not add arguments anymore:

```
public boolean popBackStack(@IdRes int destinationId, boolean inclusive)
```

So, how can I constanlty switch between the two fragments without adding them every time to back stack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pop fragments from back stack simply by adding a `popUpTo` attribute to a navigation action. This way you navigate using an action with arguments, but with pop back stack behaviour.

For example, you can add attribute `app:popUpTo="@+id/fragmentB"` to the action `action_fragmentC_to_fragmentB`. This way you'll be popping fragmentC from backstack each time you go from fragmentC to fragmentB.

[See the docs with example for this here.](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop)

There's another option, which is likely an overhead for the case you described, but that allows to use popBackStack method and send arguments - using 'navigate back with result' approach. For it fragments should implement an interface (callback) with a method that receives bundle. Use `addOnBackStackChangedListener` in the fragment manager to trigger this method, providing all the data necessary, after popBackStack is called. (Described here in the section "How to navigate back with a result?": https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/using-navigation-architecture-component-in-a-large-banking-app-ac84936a42c2, and with slightly different implementation here: [https://medium.com/@zawadz88/david-vávra-thank-you-for-this-great-article-ae3e602b880a](https://medium.com/@zawadz88/david-v%C3%A1vra-thank-you-for-this-great-article-ae3e602b880a))

Comment: And of course you can use shared ViewModel as suggested by Google to keep the necessary data accessible for fragments B and C instead of passing arguments directly from fragment to fragment. This way again you can keep on using `popBackStack`.