# how to pass a value back to previous fragment destination using Android navigation component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

let sat I have some destinations like this

from fragment A --> to fragment B --> to fragment C

I can use Safe Args to pass data from fragment A to fragment B. and also using safe args from fragment B to fragment C.

what if I want to bring a string that generated in fragment C back to fragment B or to fragment A ?

to navigate from fragment C to fragment B, I use code:

```
Navigation.findNavController(fragmentView).navigateUp()
```

and to navigate from fragment C to fragment A, I use code:

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).popBackStack(R.id.fragmentA, false)
```

so how to pass a value back to previous fragment destination ? do I have to make an action back from fragment C to fragment B and pass the value through safe args ?

really need your help. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Did you tried using interfaces?

Comment: @VivekSingh to create some listener using interface ?

Comment: if you make an action from C to A, then the B will still be in your back stack, same the C.

Comment: @ghita so what should I do ? do you ever have this problem ?

Comment: i am still stuck with this problem, thinking of a solution...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57536179/component-navigation-pop-from-backstack-with-arguments

Comment: @ghita maybe I will try to use listener, please inform me if there is an answer on your question there :)

Comment: I have used popBackStack with SharedPrefs. I will post here if I will find a better solution. Please do the same if you find a better solution, thnx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass data/bundle using navigateUp in Android Navigation Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058689/pass-data-bundle-using-navigateup-in-android-navigation-component)

Answer (score 21):

You can use the below snippet for sending data to previous fragment.

Fragment A observing the data:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<String>("key")?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { data ->
        // Do something with the data.
    }
}
```

Fragment B sending the data:

```
findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("key", data)
findNavController().popBackStack()
```

I also wrote extensions for this.

```
fun <T : Any> Fragment.setBackStackData(key: String,data : T, doBack : Boolean = true) {
    findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(key, data)
    if(doBack)
    findNavController().popBackStack()
}

fun <T : Any> Fragment.getBackStackData(key: String, result: (T) -> (Unit)) {
    findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<T>(key)?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        result(it)
    }
}
```

Usage:

Fragment A:

```
getBackStackData<String>("key") { data ->
    // Do something with the data.
}
```

Fragment B:

```
setBackStackData("key",data)
```

Note: I am using String as data. You may use any other type of variable.

Note: If you are going to use a Class as data, don't forget to add `@Parcelize` annotation and extend `Parcelable`.

Comment: perfect, if have result immediaetely replace ```.getLiveData<String>("key")?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { data ->``` on ```.get<String>("data")```

Comment: Can we send a state of a game (eg: pause) to previous fragment and show the same UI state when the fragment is launched again ?

Comment: @Chandu Yes, you may send any data type. Just declare the data type and use it.   
```enum class GameState {}   ... setBackStackData("state",GameState.Paused) ...  getBackStackData<GameState>("state") ... ```

Comment: above solution working flowless

Comment: Amazing extension :)

Answer (score 0):

i have just came across the same problem and have several options i can propose (currently considering myself which ones is best for my use case).

1. create a navigation action from fragment C back to fragment A. note that if that's all you do, your stack will now be: A-B-C-A. to avoid this, you can use `popUpTo` and `PopUpToInclusive`. see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop-example).

the disadvantage of this method is that fragment A will be cleared no matter what, and would have to re-load (and fetch all its' data again).

2. use a shared `ViewModel` between for your fragments, and observe the required value with `LiveData`. in this scenario, fragment C will update a `LiveData` value in the shared `ViewModel`, which fragment A observes. now when you go back to fragment A, your `observer` will be triggered with the value set by fragment C.
3. similar to option 2, if you are using an external data source (like a `Room` database) you can observe changes using `LiveData` in fragment A. all fragment C has to do in this case is update the data source, and fragment A will automatically be updated through the `LiveData`

Answer (score 0):

From Fragment version 1.3.0, you can use [setFragmentResultListener and setFragmentResult](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragment-result) to pass a value between two fragments

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).