# How can I pass data to the previous fragment using Android Navigation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

My app starts with `NewAdFragment` and inside this fragment, There is a button that allows user to choose the category, When the user clicks on the button I'll navigate him to `ChooserFragment` with passing categories list as an argument, There is RecyclerView inside this fragment and it shows categories.

**What do I want?** I want when the user chooses an item from RecyclerView, Then it must back to `NewAdFragment` with specific data.

I can solve this problem in a lot of ways but maybe there is a method that exists in the navigation component library already.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: use argument in navigation i hope this will help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to implement below code blocks as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61239011/4862911):

**FRAGMENT A**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
val navController = findNavController();
// We use a String here, but any type that can be put in a Bundle is supported
navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<String>("key")?.observe(
    viewLifecycleOwner) { result ->
    // Do something with the result.
  }
}
```

**FRAGMENT B**

```
navController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("key", result)
navController.popBackStack()
```

you can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62768072/4862911)

Comment: Is it required to use LiveData with it?

Comment: @SC291 yes. you must use live data.