# Navigation Component: how to return data if popbackstack was called

Tags: android, navigation

I use the navigation component in my app and now I have two fragments - **FirstFragment, SecondFragmen**t. From **SecondFragment**, I return the result to **FirstFragment**. previously, I called **setTargetFragment** and passed the data this way. Please tell me how I can now transfer data to **FirstFragment** from **SecondFragment** using **Navigation component**? to complete the **SecondFragment**, I call **navigate.popbackstack()**. but I want to end the fragment and return data. Thanks

Comment: this solution might help you [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57587499/8068914)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40085608/how-to-pass-data-from-one-fragment-to-previous-fragment
this will help you.